# Application.DoEvents() and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Tags: multithreading

I have downloaded a code from the internet and this is a few lines of it.

```
      //Notification
                lblUpdate.Text = String.Format("Loading Master File {0}...", 
                fMaster);
                Application.DoEvents();
     /// File Load Phase  
                    while (!bLoaded)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            bMaster = new Bitmap(fMaster);
                            bLoaded = true;
                        }
                        catch (OutOfMemoryException)
                        {
                            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                        }
                    }
```

in this code:
 bloaded is a boolean 
 bMaster is a bitmap
 fMaster is a string

My questions are the following :
1- What does Application.DoEvents(); do?
2- What does GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); do?

Please take into consideration that I've done research on google and did not understand , need easy to understand yet detailed explanations if possible.

Thank you for all in advance.

Comment: Please delete this code from your machine.

Comment: why? @HansPassant

Comment: The programmer that wrote this was quite clueless.  Just make sure his ignorance won't infect your programs.

Comment: Is it possible for you to leave me a detailed explications of the questions 1 and 2 and why this code is bad please?

Comment: With either a bad (corrupted) bitmap or one that is just too large, this while-loop will never end.

Comment: Read [ask] and then ask about what you really want to do, not about some shady piece of code you found.

Comment: my question was clearly about : 1- What does Application.DoEvents(); do? 2- What does GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); do?  and not if the code is good or not